# Illegal characters in path?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have following scripts:

```
function PostChartValues(meter_id, range_type_id, start_date, end_date) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetMeterReadingsTimeSeries", "Widget")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { MeterType: meter_id, DateRangeType: range_type_id, StartDate: start_date, EndDate: end_date },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#chart_loading_div").show();
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#chart_loading_div").fadeOut();
         },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#chart").html(result);
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Seçilen kritere uygun veri bulunamadı!");
        }
    }); //end ajax
} //end PostChartValues
```

code is working. But When I receive an external .js file above code, I get the error that I wrote in the title.

Why do I get this?

Comment: Can you clarify. What do you mean by an external js file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have asp.net code in there, asp.net-mvc doesn't parse external js files so you'll actuall be trying to make a request to `@Url.Action("GetMeterReadingsTimeSeries", "Widget")` which is not a valid url. You'll have to manually write the results of `Url.Action("GetMeterReadingsTimeSeries", "Widget")` in you js file.

Answer (score 2):

[Musa is absolutely right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13449448/486233), but to add to that:

One way to get around that is to provide your rendered variables in an embedded script within your HTML (or view) like so:

```
<!-- in your view -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var AJAX_URL = '@Url.Action("GetMeterReadingsTimeSeries", "Widget")';
</script>
```

Then, in your external JavaScript file:

```
function PostChartValues(meter_id, range_type_id, start_date, end_date) {
    $.ajax({
        url: AJAX_URL,
        // ..
    });
}
```

As a way to try to avoid overlapping variable names, I use all-caps.